# How can I modify the filepath in visual studio to my database on execution or setup

Tags: c#, sql, database, visual-studio, ms-access

#### **Problem**

*Written in visual studio & C#*

I have finished writing my program and it connects to a SQL database, this is currently working perfectly yet since i want to deploy this program on other computers it throws back errors due to incorrect file paths. For example in the settings part of visual studio i get this which is the filepath to my database.

Screen shot of the value I am trying to change:

[image]

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data
Source="C:\Users\Will\Dropbox\filelocation\databasename.mdb"
```

Is there a way of changing this value when I either run the program or install the program to the computer(once published?

Any help appreciated.

Thanks!

Edit: I thought about using the below code to change the file path yet I would like to only have to change this value once. Is there anyway to do this? (I tried this but since it is read only this probably wouldn't work)
`Properties.Settings.Default.Value`

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

Edit 2: Trying configuration manager, is it possible to change the values using something along the lines of

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings.
```

Comment: Have you though of asking the user for the path during the installation process? Or maybe creating the path if it does not exist?

Comment: I considered it but was unsure of how i would go about this process

Comment: experimenting with new project, setup project now. Thanks

Comment: [You should answer your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) now write, [solved], etc. I don't think you have enough rep. I'll add a wiki answer with your response for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix the issue thanks for any suggestions I used

```
 //updating config file
XmlDocument XmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
//Loading the Config file
XmlDoc.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);
foreach (XmlElement xElement in XmlDoc.DocumentElement)
{
    if (xElement.Name == "connectionStrings")
    {
        //setting the coonection string
        xElement.FirstChild.Attributes[2].Value = con;
    }
}
//writing the connection string in config file
XmlDoc.Save(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);
```

Along with OpenFileDialog if anyone is intrested. The database now loads fine.